# Code coverage tools for qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, qooxdoo

[qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org) offers an excellent unit testing framework, but no code coverage tools. [Coveralls](https://coveralls.io/) is great, but only for public projects; what about private/commercial or projects that are yet to be published?

There are a lot of JavaScript code coverage tools around: [Blanket.js](http://blanketjs.org/), [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul), [JSCover](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/)... but considering qooxdoo's complexity and its application construction principles, applying one of these might turn into a non-trivial problem. Has anyone had any success with the tools listed above? Which one works best (if at all)?

Comment: Meanwhile, I've tried Istanbul - looks fairly promising. It provides a Node-based code instrumentation tool, and collects coverage data into the `__coverage__` variable. I think instrumentation could be (one day) integrated into [QxCompiler](https://github.com/johnspackman/qxcompiler) (continuous?) compilation pipeline, as well as coverage reporting into TestRunner.

Answer (score 2):

The qooxdoo framework itself uses karma to run its test suit on travis and karma-coverage to report coverage to coveralls. The qooxdoo karma integration is in https://github.com/qooxdoo/karma-qooxdoo which you can install via npm.

If you use the qooxdoo testing framework, then this might be your best bet, since qooxdoo core development relies on this as well.

Comment: Nice tip, but I don't seem to get it working. I installed karma-qooxdoo via npm(0.6.0), and when I run the karma start command with phantomjs browser, i run into this errror:   undefined is not an object (evaluating 'qx.core.Init')
  at node_modules/karma-qooxdoo/qooxdoo-adapter.js:149

Comment: we use chrome/ff and are about to include ie and others ... but this is happening on the master branch only, so if you are using 5.0.2 then there may be issues ... same with phantomjs which we abandoned after some early experiments.